# is difference between array in variable and array from file in perl?

Tags: perl, file, hash

I have something like this

```
my $variable1  =[ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' ];
```

and something like this:

```
use File::Slurp;
my $variable2 = read_file( 'filename.txt' );
```

in filename.txt is

```
[ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' ]
```

What's difference? And how can I read from file informations to variable2 and get same results like variable1?

Because when I later want read only one word from file it's something wrong.

Comment: If you are looking for a way to serialize data, you should know that there are already many such formats and modules to use, and you would be better off using one of them than inventing your own.

Comment: I cannot find any hashes in that question. please read an introductory book on perl. soon.

Comment: can you say me some of them??? I will like to study it.

Comment: http://onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File::Slurp can give you the data in the form you want it (as an array ref). But your file "filename.txt" should have a different content for this to work: every value should be on one line

```
A
B
C
D
```

then

```
use File::Slurp;
my $variable2 = read_file( 'filename.txt', array_ref => 1, chomp => 1 );
```

will read this in as an array reference.

Answer (score 2):

> Whats difference?

One is Perl. The other is characters in a file (and so is read in as a string).

> And how can I read from file informations to variable2 and get same results like variable1 ???

You would have to parse the string into a Perl data structure.

This is usually done by storing the data in a standard file format. Your example almost conforms to the [JSON](http://json.org/) specification so you can use [a JSON parser](https://metacpan.org/module/JSON) if you replace your `'` characters with `"`s.

Comment: Doesn't JSON use double quotes only?